# express command not recognized by the mac terminal

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am new to nodeJS and I am trying to install express. I have already installed node and npm. I am using Max OSX(10.10.1). I am getting error:

```
-bash: express: command not found
```

I have gone through all the questions here but couldn't get any answer to my problem. I tried these commands:

```
sudo npm install -g express
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

I tried to install it locally without the -g. 
Also, when I did a sudo npm init, I saw that express existed in the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"orientjs": "^2.1.0",
"express-generator": "^4.13.1",
"express": "^2.5.11"
}
```

I added the below paths in .bash_profile one at a time. These are the paths where express folder is there.

```
.node/bin, 
.node/lib/node_modules in the 
/usr/local/node_modules
```

but it is not present in /usr/local/bin folder. I feel this might be the reason why it throws the error mentioned above.

I tried to link express to npm but it gave an error:

```
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "link"        
"express"    
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, 
stat '$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/express'
```

How do I make sure that express is recognized by the terminal? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `express` executable is installed when you run `sudo npm install -g express-generator`.

In Mac OS it should be installed in the following directory:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator
```

And the executable itself is installed in:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
```

A symbolic link is also created in:

```
/usr/local/bin/express
```

Comment: In my case, I do not have the express link in /usr/local/bin. It got generated  for node and npm when I installed them but not for express. How do I create the symlink for express manually?

Comment: Do you have it here `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express`?

Comment: No. When I ran sudo npm install -g express-generator, it automatically got installed in $HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express

Comment: Then you can go to `/usr/local/bin` and run `ln -s $HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express .`

Comment: But if you run with `sudo` it should have installed in `/usr/local/lib` and not your `$HOME` directory.

Comment: I really don't know why it didn't with sudo. I uninstalled express and retried it and again it went to HOME directory. But the command you mentioned above worked. Thanks.